# Service Stack XmlServiceClient null result in VS 2013 but works fine in VS 2012

Tags: servicestack, visual-studio-2013

When I build my project in VS 2012 the following code works fine, however when I build it in VS 2013 I get null objects on all of the calls.

Any ideas why?

```
var client = new XmlServiceClient(apiHost);
   client.LocalHttpWebRequestFilter += (request) =>
   {
     request.Headers.Add("x-api-token", Session["token"].ToString());
     request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", Session["key"].ToString());
     request.Headers.Add("x-user-id", Session["uid"].ToString());
   };
var _order = client.Get(new OrderLookupRequest { Id = 176352 });
var _orderItems = client.Get(new OrderItemLookupRequest { OrderId = 176352 });
```

_order and _orderItems are both null when built using VS2013.

I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web;
```

Comment: same .Net version ? or are you using .Net 4.5.1 in VS 2013?

Comment: Our application is using 4.5 not 4.5.1

Comment: It was a version mismatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a version mismatch in the application.